# Show message when max size in datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using datatables in my web and when pagging the client has requested to limit the number of results(500 max).
I need to display a message in the case there are more than 500 rows but I don't know how to do that.
Any idea? Is it possible to do it for every table in the application or it is necessary to modify every table.

Thanks!

Comment: Is it server-side or client-side data? That seems a strange thing to do - the whole point of paging is to display ALL the requested data in a manageable way.

Comment: Do you want some more logic in case there are more rows in the grid or just a simple alert ?

Comment: I know it is strange but the client only wants to display 500 rows max. From the server-side is sent the 500 rows so there is no restriction in the client, but it is necessary to alert(only alert) the user that there are more results which are not shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the jQuery method .length() to get the number of rows in the table.

```
var n = $("#example").find("tr").length;
```

After that I checked if n is bigger than the allowed length and if so I displayed a message informing the user that the table will be limited.

You can find my jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/MarkusToe/xbas9wd4/).

Answer (score 0):

You can do a check up when the user defines the number of rows; which has to be visible.
Lets say the user number is specified in a prompt box triggered by a button:

```
<button onclick="yourFunction('YourTableId')">Set Data Number</button>

function yourFunction(table_id) {

    var rows = $(table_id).jqxDataTable('getRows'); //number of all rows
    var datanumber= prompt("Please enter your data number", rows.length); //rows.length = the maximun number of data available as default value
    if (datanumber!= null&&datanumber<=rows.length) {
        if (datanumber<rows.legth){
            alert("there are " + (rows.length-datanumber) +"more data to display")
         }
    }
    else{
       alert("insert a number from 0 to "+ rows.length)
    }
}
```

also don't forget the [JQuery documentation](https://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/jqxdatatable/jquery-datatable-api.htm)